# Button Command with class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I'm trying to get this right but so far no luck. Would appreciate it if someone can help me with it.

```
import tkinter
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,text='Average',command=self.average)
        self.button1.pack()
        tkinter.mainloop()
    def average(self):
        self.mini_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.avg_mess = tkinter.Label(self.mini_window,text='Results:')
        self.avg_result_var = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.avg_result_display = tkinter.Label(self.mini_window,textvariable=self.avg_result_var)
        self.avg_mess.pack()
        self.avg_result_display.pack()
        self.button2 = tkinter.Button(self.mini_window,text='Calculate',command=self.avg_calc)
        self.button2.pack()
    def avg_calc(self):
        self.avg_result = (100+300+80)/3
        self.avg_result_var.set(self.avg_result)
gui = MyGUI()
```

The problem occurs when the `Calculate` button is clicked but the `avg_result_var` does not change its value. And hence the `avg.result_display` remains blank. I suspect there is something wrong with the function call when the button is pressed. I'm using Python 3.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost doing it correctly, but there are a couple of problems

First, the result never changes because you use the same numbers each time you do a calculation. The result is always the same so it appears that it is not changing.

The second problem is that you're creating two instances of `Tk`. Tkinter isn't designed to work like that, and it causes problems such as the one you are observing. If you need additional pop-up windows, use `Toplevel` rather than `Tk`.

Here's a modified version of your program, though I've added a random number in the computation so you can see it change each time.

```
import Tkinter as tkinter
import random
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,text='Average',command=self.average)
        self.button1.pack()
        tkinter.mainloop()
    def average(self):
        self.mini_window = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.avg_mess = tkinter.Label(self.mini_window,text='Results:')
        self.avg_result_var = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.avg_result_display = tkinter.Label(self.mini_window,textvariable=self.avg_result_var)
        self.avg_mess.pack(fill="both")
        self.avg_result_display.pack()
        self.button2 = tkinter.Button(self.mini_window,text='Calculate',command=self.avg_calc)
        self.button2.pack()
    def avg_calc(self):
        x = random.randint(100,200)
        self.avg_result = (100+300+x)/3
        print "result:", self.avg_result
        self.avg_result_var.set(self.avg_result)
gui = MyGUI()
```